# left sidebar content gallery using jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, gallery

Im looking for a jquery gallery plugin with left sidebar content selector, would you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a Look at:
http://www.slidesjs.com/
The Product-Example has a right sidebar. ( A little bit coding, then the sidebar is left)

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for free download examples? 
check: http://www.pikachoose.com/
it has free download with different options
but if you are looking to pay:
check this : http://www.tn3gallery.com/examples/tn3_eris_vertical/